# How do i find out what is slowing down my page load in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pageload, performance

[http://shanamccormick.com](http://shanamccomrick.com)

The page loads all the images and then says "(1 item remaining) Waiting on http:// shanamccormick com..."  How can i see what it is waiting to load here?? and why does it take sooo long?

The index.html file uses a couple small internal JS and one external JS located within my website (jquery.min) The size of the external JS file is 54kb.

Comment: The page doesn't exist anymore? or is it: http://shanamccormick.com/#sthash.zBGBpmJp.dpbs ? misstype?

Answer (score 4):

IE8 has a Javascript profiler, like Firebug for Firefox. 
But I think you need [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to profile the performance of the HTTP request/response.

[image]

If you want the Javascript developer tools (including profiler) I recommend moving to IE8, but if you can't,
[IE7 has downloadable dev tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E59C3964-672D-4511-BB3E-2D5E1DB91038&displaylang=en), like IE8's built-in capability.

Comment: +1 for Fiddler - I reckon that's the best tool for the problem as described.

Comment: IE7 dev tools link is dead -- "We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found."  Are they still available somewhere?  Is this the same http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359 ?

Answer (score 2):

I have a few solutions that might help. I learned of these from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032550/how-do-you-do-page-performance-tests) I asked earlier:

- [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html) is a JavaScript file you can insert into your pages to simulate some Firebug features in browsers that are not named "Firefox". Firebug Lite creates the variable "firebug" and doesn't affect or interfere with HTML elements that aren't created by itself.
- [WebWait](http://webwait.com/) is a website timer. Use WebWait to benchmark your website or test the speed of your web connection. Timing is accurate because WebWait pulls down the entire website into your browser, so it takes into account Ajax/Javascript processing and image loading which other tools ignore.
- Also, the [IE JavaScript Real Performance Tester](http://www.codeplex.com/IEJst) can test your scripts.

Hope these help!

Answer (score 0):

The page doesn't exist anymore? or is it: shanamccormick.com ? misstype?

Anyway I've found that googles IE8.js (for IE7 and less) (https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) takes up to 1 minute to load (on a computer from that time) every page load... could that have been the problem?